# Getting Stringstream to read from character A to B in a String

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

Is there some way to get StringStream to read characters A through B of a string?

For example, something like (but not):

```
stringstream mystringstream;
mystringstream.read(char* s, streamsize n, **int firstcharacter**);
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: By A through B I mean, for example, the third through fifth characters.

EDIT: Example: get characters three through five of "abcdefghijklmnop" would give "cde".

Comment: The question is not clear. What do you mean? Clarify yourself.

Comment: Why not just read characters A through B of the string itself?

Comment: Are “A” and “B” stand-in for *positions* in the string or do you mean *character values*?

Comment: Please provide an example with input and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

or, if you need a *substring* in position A through B, you can do

```
string s = mystring.substr(A, B-A+1); // the second parameter is the length
```

if this must be a stringstream, you can do

```
string s = mystringstream.str().substr(A, B-A+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `substr`-method:

```
std::string foo = "asdfersdfwerg";
std::cout << foo.substr(5, 4) << std::endl;
```

This will print `rsdf`.